# How to dynamicly set value radiobutton with JS in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

I'm a novice in JS and trying to put some text dynamicly as a optionvalue for the radio button. But I can't seem to make the text appear. What am I doing wrong?

HTML

```
<form id="formulier">
<label for="a">
<input type="radio" id="a" name="a">
<!--here I want to show a value from an array ic answer[0]-->
<!--tried also this:   <script>document.write(answer[0]);</script>    -->
</label>
</form>
```

JS

```
var answer = <?php echo json_encode($antwoorden); ?>;
const a = document.getElementById("a");

// Ive tried:
a.value = answer[0];
a.innerHTML = answer[0];
a.innerText = answer[0];
```

None of them shows up. How can I make the text show up in HTML?

Comment: You are setting the value of a radio button; it won't be visible on the page.

Comment: How can I make it visible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't output text by setting it as a value of radio buttons.

Instead you could set it as the textual content of the related `label` element.

To be able to select the associated `label` easily with JavaScript, assign the same `class` as the `ìd` of the `<input type="radio">` element to it.

HTMl & JS Snippet

```js
var answer = 'Dynamically inserted Message';
const a = document.getElementsByClassName("a")[0];
a.innerHTML = answer;
```

```html
<form id="formulier">
  <input type="radio" id="a" name="a">
  <label for="a" class="a"></label>
</form>
```

Comment: This will indeed add the text, but the checkbox disappears

Comment: @micka I have tested my answer and the radio checkbox stays - just the label's text value changes as intended. Check if you really used the method `getElementsByClassName("a")[0]` and not  previous `document.getElementById("a")`.

Comment: You're right. I wrapped the <label> around the <input>, to get them on 1 line. That makes the chekcbox disappear. Cause somehow, here they dont appear on the same line.

Comment: [link](https://imgur.com/a/HfYGTre) The first radiobutton is done with your method the rest are done with div tags.